# Nonlinear least squares uniqueness

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-rank, least-squares, jacobian

Suppose I have a nonlinear least squares objective function I want to minimize:
$$
\chi^2(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\mathbf{x})^2 = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})^T \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})
$$
Now suppose the solution is not unique, so that $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ both represent global minimum values of $\chi^2$.

I would like to get a sense for ``how big'' is the solution space (i.e. how much non-uniqueness is there in the objective function?). For example, are there a finite number of solutions or an infinite number?

Is there some way to answer these questions by analyzing the Jacobian of the objective function,
$$
J = \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
$$
For example, would the size of the nullspace of the Jacobian provide any information on the size of the solution space for the $\mathbf{x}$ values? Or is it possible that the Jacobian can be full rank and still have a non-unique solution?

Alternatively, suppose I assume that $\mathbf{x}$ is a solution, and I manage to find a class of matrices $A$ such that
$$
\chi^2(A \mathbf{x}) = \chi^2(\mathbf{x})
$$
Certainly if I could find *all* such matrices $A$, then I would know not only the dimension of the solution space, but all the solutions themselves! But this is quite difficult for my problem!. It seems to me that the set of all such matrices $A$ forms a group. Is this group somehow related to the Jacobian?

I have not found anything in the literature addressing these types of questions. Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I am asking about global minima, not local

Comment: Thats my question. In cases where there is more than 1 global minima, are there any techniques to characterize the size of the solution space?

Comment: Start by correcting your question. You confuse minimizer and minimum. It's hard to have a serious conversation when you show such sloppiness. It would also be nice if you decided whether the global minimizers are isolated or in a continuum.

Comment: I think you need something like an interval-analysis based branch and bound global optimizer which produces a set of boxes in which the global optimum may lie. The difficulty is getting it to run fast enough and produce small enough boxes, and not have extraneous boxes (which per the solver it can not rule out having global optima).

Comment: Yes ultimately I would like to look into numerical solutions, however first I am just trying to understand if there is any connection between the nullspace of the Jacobian and the number of global minima

Comment: The Jacobian is only providing local information, so I don't think can tell you much about global or "distant" behavior. For example minimize 0 subject to x*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3) = 0 has global optima at x = 0, 1, 2, 3 .What does the Jacobian at x = 0 tell you about the other local optima?